# Uno Platform Pathicon no longer displays correctly

Tags: uno-platform

My app uses PathIcon for the bottomnavigationbar.  There was an update on the package Uno.UI - it was the update from 3.10.0-dev.474 yo 3.10.0-dev.479.  Once I updated to 479 or later- my pathicons are now washed out- to the point where I can barely see them.  The code in my app has not changed.  What should I do?  For now I have reverted to 474.
Here is an example:
[image]

Comment: This seems like a bug. Can you post it as an issue on Uno Platform's GitHub repo? https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues

Comment: Thanks Martin!  I posted the issue here: https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/7131